# Child_Process Multiple Commands

Tags: node.js, linux, process, windows-subsystem-for-linux, child-process

I want to execute multiple commands in one `spawn` function without using the `shell` parameter, as it breaks my code. Let's say I wanted to run this command using the `spawn` function: `ls && node app.js`, how would I do this?